# Specific style of nomenclature?

Tags: glossaries, nomenclature

I need to include the nomenclature in my thesis and my university use the below style, could anyone suggest how to produce this style?
Also include greek symbols, sub, and superscripts.

[image]

**Edit**

Actually, I wrote this

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[acronym,toc,nopostdot,nonumberlist]{glossaries}                       
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\setlength{\columnsep}{25pt}
\setlength{\glsdescwidth}{10cm}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols}     
\newglossary[gree]{greeklist}{greei}{greeg}{List of Greek Symbols} 
\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit  }{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\makeglossaries    
%===================================================
%----------------Roman Symbols----------------------
%===================================================
\newglossaryentry{diameter}{name=\ensuremath{D, d},
    description={Diameter of bearing, journal respectively},
    unit={\si{m}},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{clearance}{name=\ensuremath{c},
    description={radial clearance},
    unit={\si{m}},
    type=symbolslist}

%===================================================
%------------------Greek Symbols--------------------
%===================================================
\newglossaryentry{speed}{name={\ensuremath{\omega}},
description={Rotating Speed},
unit={\si{rad/s}},
type=greeklist}

\newglossaryentry{epsilon}{name={\ensuremath{\epsilon}},
description={Eccentricity ratio},
unit={},
type=greeklist}

\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{%
\begin{longtable}{lp{0.6\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}}
\end{longtable}
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  
\bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
\hline
\endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline }}
```

Comment: Take a look at the `glossaries` package and its `long3col` style. This gives a starter, I think

Comment: Do you really want to recreate the exact same horrible output? Look at the line spacing. And the horrible rules.

Comment: @Johannes_B - As I mentioned in the question, this is the style that my University use and I agree with you, it is horrible.

Comment: Check with them. Many many users are putting time and effort into recreating something they don't need to recreate exactly. University guidelines are guidelines, no strict rules (in most cases). I would definitely ask somebod who has the knowledge, because recreating *Word* madness with LaTeX is pure horror.

Comment: You are definitely right, they use *word* as the main program (Pro. and students) however, I write my thesis in *LaTeX* for the more advantages I have than using *MS word*.